# Neither BigText nor FitText work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I have this simple html snippet

```
<div id="bigtext" style="width: 300px">
    <div>The elusive</div>
    <div>BIGTEXT</div>
    <div>plugin exclusively</div>
    <div>captured on film</div>
</div>
```

with no CSS enabled so it doesn't interfere with anything. Then I have a simple Javascript file with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bigtext").bigtext();
});
```

Also in my html I load bigtext.js. I have confirmed that both Javascript files are being loaded through an alert, but the text does not resize to fit. I have also tried this using FitText and that did not work either. I have copied the BigText example exactly from the [website](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/) but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: have you included jQuery library

Comment: The website demo uses an id. _Maybe_ it requires an id instead of a class reference for the div?

Comment: Yes I have included jQuery

Comment: Any javascript errors in your developer tool (Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools)?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPropertyValue' of null bigtext.js:36
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bigtext' javascripts.js:3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a look at the [**bigtext demo**](https://github.com/zachleat/BigText/blob/master/demo/simpleDemoDiv.html) on GitHub and added a couple of lines as below and it seems to be working...

```
<body>
    <div id="bigtext">
        <div>The elusive</div>
        <div>BIGTEXT</div>
        <div>plugin exclusively</div>
        <div>captured on film</div>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bigtext.js"></script>
    <script>
    var bt = BigText.noConflict(true);
    $.fn.bt = bt.jQueryMethod;

    $('#bigtext').bt();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [BigText plugin](https://github.com/zachleat/BigText/blob/master/bigtext.js) expects an ID to work.

Comment: I originally had it as an ID but that didn't work either. I will edit my post to reflect that.